# Dislin and codeblocks : undefined reference

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to use Dislin library in order to plot graph from data...

Thus, I dowloaded the .deb : `dislin-10.6.linux.i586_64.deb`.
Afer using a `sudo dpkg -i` I exported the links with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/dislin`

After a look at `/usr/local/dislin` everything seemes to be there.

Now I'm trying to run a first example on codeblocks, I added to the build option, in the compiler part, the folder `usr/local/dislin` (where is discpp.h)

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "discpp.h"

int main ()
{
 int n = 100, i, ic;
 double fpi = 3.1415926 / 180.0, step, x;
 double xray[100], y1ray[100], y2ray[100];
 Dislin g;
 //original code in example http://www.mps.mpg.de/1757371/exa_cpp#section_2
 return 0;
}
```

`

But I can't build my project, i have the errors :

- `undefined reference to 'Dislin::Dislin()'`
- `undefined reference to 'Dislin::~Dislin()'`

I feel that a forget to linked something to codeblocks but i can't figure out what. I'm struglling since a while could help me ?

Comment: The library you use, is it a header-only library, or does it come with actual library files that you need to *link* with?

Comment: It come with library files I added in the linker directory tab `/usr/local/dislin` and `/usr/local/dislin/lib` but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found it.

I needed to add not only the search directory of the linker but also the .so in the linker setting of codeblocks from the folder /usr/local/dislin

So simple...